# Java parse String into Query

Tags: java, parsing

we have two-dimensional array of ints:

```
int[][] XYZ = new int[][]{
              { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
              { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 },
              { 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 },
              { 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2 },
              { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 }
            };
```

and a String:

`String zapytanie = "((XYZ[i][0]==3 && XYZ[i][1]==4) || (XYZ[i][1]==3 || XYZ[i][2]==7))"`

Query is generated dynamiccly and passed to String.

what i want to do is parse this String in for without adding 
external  tools/components.

```
for(int i=0;i<XYZ.length;i++)
                    {
                        //todo  parse here this expression
                    }
```

we want to find all rows that match query in the String and return them.

My problem is i do not know how to parse String into Query. Like removing this " " from String zapytanie and execute it.

I'm pretty sure i can not use eval, but still new thing to learn so i tried it :)

first imported

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
```

Second

```
            ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
            ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("JavaScript");

            for(int i=0;i<XYZ.length;i++)
            {
                engine.eval(zapytanie);
            }
```

error: `ReferenceError: "XYZ" is not defined.`

Any idea how to fix that error, and can you tell me other methods to do the task without using javascript here?

I made a post-order tree from my query, but i was wondering is there a faster way, then using this tree:

a is XYZ[i][0], b is XYZ[i][1] and so on.

from `zapytanie = ((a=3 and b=4) or (b=3 or c=7))`

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwGVT.png

And i do not know how to use this tree smart way

Comment: it looks like you haven't tried anything yet. show us your attempt

Comment: Your string looks like it could become quite complex so I'd probably use an external parser library or something like Javassist to add the code defined in the string directly to the method. Any reason why you don't want to use a library?

Comment: Cause i get this task from somebody and i must not use it.
Philip - any hint ?

Comment: Then please ask that somebody why you must not use that. If it is for learning purposes then please state so, if it is for other reasons then please state them. If the person who tasked you can't provide good reasons then reject the task. ;)

Comment: I am studying and this is a task to finish my subject :)
Thanks for any tips guys!
Hope you  understand what i'am trying to say :)

Comment: @PhilippSander i updated the first post, any hint now :) ?

Answer (score 0):

Well one option is to use [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval), though I wouldn't recommend using it for anything in real life as it is a huge security hole.

If you cannot use eval then I suppose you need to educate yourself on parsers, specifically [Operator-precedence parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator-precedence_parser) I'd say.

Comment: It is java not javascript.

Comment: I'm pretty sure i can't use eval, but still i checked this option.
I get error sasying "ReferenceError: "XYZ" is not defined."
Do you know how can i make this reference?
Thank you for your tip :)

Comment: @talex Uh I don't know why I thought it was JS, probably because I'm working with it a lot now :-)

Comment: @yami I recommend looking at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605032/is-there-an-eval-function-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself :)

1. let's say query was `((a<=1 and b=4) or (b=2 and c=7))`. We get the `query` as a `String` - from user input.

and `a is XYZ[i][0]`, `b is XYZ[i][1]` from the database *`int[][] array`* and so on.

1. First what i did is check if the query is ok - regarding number of left/right brackets. If not then stop here.
2. i change query from `String` that equals `((a<=1 and b=4) or (b=2 and c=7))` to *Reverse Polish notation* so now my `String` equals `a<=1 b=4 and b=2 c=7 and or`
3. RPN is in postorder order. I created a tree from it regarding this order and added elements to JTree.
   It looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpjJn.png
4. I travel my tree in postorder way and parse each of the items.

   If i find operator like `and` or `or` i take 2 childs of them and use one of the logic operators regarding operator above, so: `&&` or `||`.
5. On the final i have root which have only `Boolean` value that tells use if this row was ok or not.

   6. if it was ok - then we write down that row.